# Help with nautilus and Dropbox

Tags: nautilus, dropbox

I tried to download dropbox, which worked ok but then I got a message to restart nautilus for dropbox to work properly.  But when I click the button that says "restart nautilus" nothing happens.

I need to let you know I am totally un-techy, so please could you keep things as straight forward and simple as possible?

Is there a simple fix that a total noob with no technical knowledge can do?

Comment: Log out and log back in. That would solve any issues you might be facing.

Comment: If no nautilus window is open it may not be obvious that nautilus was restarted. Click **Next** and continue with Dropbox configuration.

Comment: Unless you have a nautilus window open, i.e. you are browsing files on your computer, you will not see anything happen when you click "restart nautilus" - and this is to be expected. What happens when you restart nautilus is that all windows which allow you to browse files are *closed* because nautilus is the process that manages them. You can restart nautilus manually from the terminal using `nautilus -q`.

Comment: Did you install it using `nautilus-dropbox`?

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox requires Nautilus to be restarted for its integration. If clicking on *Restart nautilus* doesn't work for some reason, just logging out and logging back in would restart Nautilus and solve your problem.

Once logged in, Dropbox would autostart and ask you to connect to your account to proceed further.